# Maven Project can't import log4j2 classes

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I created maven project, I addded log4j2 dependencies to POM, and my project obviously can't import LogManager class. Why? That's output from maven console.

```
  c:\Users\Dawid\Desktop\Pracbaza\my-project>java -cp target\my-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.spica.project.App
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
    at com.spica.project.App.<clinit>(App.java:7)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've added those dependencies to the pom, so **maven** knows that your project depends on log4j, but you're not executing maven right now. you're using **the java executable** to run your compiled code. java has no idea what a pom.xml is (since maven is an external tool).

you have several options:

1. list all of your dependencies in the cp argument, not just your jar. so `java -cp target\your.jar;path\to\log4j2.jar;anything;else`
2. list your dependencies in your jar file's [`MANIFEST.MF` file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html). you can either list absolute paths (BAD IDEA) or file names and place your libs alongside your jar
3. package your jar as either [`jar-with-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html) or [`onejar`](https://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/). that way it'll pack all the libs alongside your own code and will be able to find them. there is a difference between these 2 options that you better understand before you pick one.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your log4j jar is not there in the classpath while running your code. Try adding the log4j jar in your classpath (in `-cp` switch).